# Open a ipython notebook- No knowledge about python as of yet

Tags: python, ipython

I need to open a ipython notebook (.ipynb extension file) to look for some work done by a previous colleague. However, I do not have a knowledge of how the python structure works. Can someone guide me on what should be the easiest way to look at the file?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install [iPython](http://ipython.org/), either on its own or as part of a prepackaged distribution such as [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads). You can then open iPython Notebook with your browser and find the notebook of your interest on your drive.

[image]